# Progress bar 9patch image horizontal scale

Tags: android

I am using a 9patch image for my progressbar's custom progress fill.  The image shows in the progress bar but the problem is that the image is 20px and the progress bar height is 50px leaving black for the last 30px. Can i have my 9patch image grow to fit the progress bars height?
this is my android:progressDrawable

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#333333" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/test_progress" />
</item>
```

this is my image
[image: 9patch]

Answer (score 0):

> Can i have my 9patch image grow to fit the progress bars height?

Yes, you just have to define the stretchable area on the vertical section of your 9 patch ( which requires a solid black 1 pixel width line on the left border of your image). It's a little confusing at first, so I recommend you read some documentation to help wrap your head around it.

9 patch docs - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Creating/previewing 9 patches - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: I do have a solid 1px line on the left side. The image is a green square with a 1px black stroke on the outside and i also have the lines for the nine patch. Would the black stroke through off android?

Comment: The single pixel outside border (your stretchable/padding regions) is not included in the image, so you should be able to still have a 1 pixel stroke. It's hard to debug without actually seeing your image and 9 patch, if you could post it, it would be easier to see if anything is wrong with it.